# Loading multiple USB devices using one power supply without needing a PC

Tags: usb, power-supply

I work in a web development company and we have many mobile devices that we need to test our software on.

We charge these devices each with their own adapter plugged into a socket, but that  clutters up the place a lot. We'd like to use some sort of extension cord that has multiple USB ports that can charge all of these devices.

We bought a 10 port USB hub with its own adapter to charge all these devices, but it itself needed to be connected to a computer or else it would not power the devices. We don't want to keep a PC powered up just to be able to load the devices.

My question is: does anybody know of a multi USB (10+) power supply that:

1. Can load multiple devices at once (preferable even multiple power hungry devices like tablets)?
2. Itself can be connected to one wall socket to get power ?
3. Does not need a computer to be able to start loading the devices?

Comment: if it just needs to be a device, maybe use a raspberry pi, or maybe a USB OTG cable from one of your test devices to get your hub to detect a host device?

Comment: I tried to connect a usb cable to the usb in port on the hub, but that did not help. Are you saying there exists some other usb device other then a full fledges pc that would do the trick? I'd prefer to not use a pi, but some small usb plug would work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: well the pi comes to mind cause its small and cheap, and well, is a computer where it matters.

Comment: VTC: 1) We don't do product suggestions, 2) This has nothing to do with a computer as defined in the help center.